# Extending a class in Data Annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to find out if there is a way to extend a class in DataAnnotations in MVC for the metadata.

For example:

If I have a model called Vehicle which contains all of the basic properties that any automobile shares, and then I have a Truck model and a Car model. Both of which are subclasses of the Vehicle model.

Now assume Vehicle contains a property for Engine Size and Vehicle Weight, Truck contains the property Towing Capacity and Car contains the property Trunk Capacity.

Is there a way for me to specify only once the metadata for the Properties that are shared in Vehicle?

I've tried something similar to:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(VehicleMD))]
public partial class Vehicle
{
   public class VehicleMD
   {
       [Display(Name = "Engine Size")]
       public double EngineSize {get;set;}

       [Display(Name = "Vehicle Weight")]
       public double VehicleWeight {get;set;}
    }
 }
```

But in the views that use the Truck or Car model the Metadata is not applied unless I also specify the annotations in partial classes for Truck and Car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Because of the way the engine is reflecting on your classes to get your annotations, they need to be applied to the child-most class.

Your other option is to directly apply the DataAnnotations to the class in question rather than using a separate Metadata Type.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! Was just curious because in my implementation of this problem I actually have 6 different models that extend from a single model. Figured it would be much cleaner and maintainable if I could just change the DataAnnotation for the parent class and it affect all of the children instead of having to put every annotation in each class.